# Connect to a MSSQL DB using Web.config

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, web-config

I have created a `ASP.NET C# MVC` project. I am trying to connect it to a `MSSQL` DB. In the `Web.config` file i added the following;

```
  <connectionStrings>
     <add name="sdbconnection" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
         connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename="C:\Users\o\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\ppl\ppl\App_Data\ppldb.mdf";Integrated Security=True" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

But, the above code is incorrect ; I want it to be as follows;

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="sdbconnection" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
         connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|ppldb.mdf;Integrated Security=True" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

But What is `DataDirectory` ? Where do i specify it ?

What is `name="sdbconnection"` ? Can i give any name that i want ?

Comment: http://www.connectionstrings.com/

Answer (score 2):

**First question**
Quoting [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478948.aspx):

> The |DataDirectory| portion of the connection string specifies that
>   the MDF file is located inthe App_Data directory

Moreover you can change it using following function:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("DataDirectory", "D:\database");
```

**Second question**
name="sdbconnection" allows you to use specified conection string. So in your code you can write:

```
string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["sdbconnection"].ConnectionString;
```

to acces this connection string

Answer (score 0):

Name is use to identify and use code your applications 
Please refer this article http://www.connectionstrings.com/Articles/Show/store-connection-string-in-web-config
Data Directory is usually App_Data folder and in web.config file name is use to use connection string in the application

Ex:String conn=ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Your name at web.config file"].ConnectionString;

or
String conn=ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Your name at web.config file"].toString();